# In ARIMA models, given identical performance and same number of total parameters, is a pure AR model preferred over an ARMA model?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, model-comparison

Say ARMA(5,0) and ARMA(3,2) provide the same (and best) cross-validation results. Is there any sense in which we can appeal to the principle of parsimony to argue in favour of ARMA(5,0)?

Comment: What is your BIC of both model?

Comment: It's purely a hypothetical situation, so I don't have BIC results, but we assume them to be equal. Although I guess it is possible to differentiate a model if we used a combination of metrics, like AIC, AICc and BIC.

Comment: @RaymondHancock, no, because if the likelihoods of the two models are equal, then AIC, AICc and BIC will be equal, too.

Comment: Thanks. So is there an argument here for parsimony or is it, as usual, dependent on context?

Comment: As far as I understand, parsimony cannot be an argument here because both models have the same number of parameters and are equally parsimonious.